# Displaying bar plot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a barplot with `midwest` dataset. However, when I run the code, I do not see anything in my `plots` window

```
library(ggplot2)
try(data('midwest',package='ggplot2'))
for (s in unique(midwest$state)) {
  state_data = subset(midwest, state == s)
  ggplot(state_data, aes(x=county, y=percprof)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to print the object explicitly. If you're using Rstudio, you can flip through the resulting plots using left and right arrow button.

```
for (s in unique(midwest$state)) {
  state_data = subset(midwest, state == s)
  print(
    ggplot(state_data, aes(x=county, y=percprof)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a great opportunity for facetting, rather than using a for loop, if you'd rather have them on one figure. Try:

```
ggplot(midwest) +
geom_bar(aes(county, percprof), stat = "identity") +
facet_wrap(~state)
```

You'll have to play with the x axis to get it to read clearly..